# EE 3.0 $.ee_filebrowser.add_trigger console errors

Tags: file-uploads, javascript

I’m converting an add-on from EE 2 to EE 3. It uses $.ee_filebrowser.add_trigger. As far as I can that still exists but I get a console error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined`

I can’t quite figure out what to do. I’ve tried to dicipher it in the minified code but I can’t quote figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. did you ever figure out a fix or did you perhaps file this as a bug with EllisLab?

Comment: I had to stop working on the add-on I was working on so I never did figure it out. I’ll be returning to that add-on in the next couple of weeks so if it’s still an issue, hopefully we can get it sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had time to circle back around to this and finish up my add-on. I don’t think the FilePicker service was documented when I started the question, but it certainly is now:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/services/filepicker.html

But I needed to make specific links in my add-on open with a specific directory but I would not necessarily know before hand. I needed to make the FilePicker links available to my template so I could select them based on the upload directory. So I did this:

```
// Load the FilePicker
$filePicker = ee('CP/FilePicker')->make();

// Class that gets EE's upload directories
$uploadDirectories = new UploadDirectories();

// Add each directories upload link to array
$modalLinks = array();
foreach ($uploadDirectories as $dir) {
    $modalLinks[$dir['id']] = array(
        'link' => $filePicker->setDirectories($dir['id'])
            ->getLink(lang('field_type_add_image'))
            ->setAttribute('class', 'btn action js-ansel-add-image')
            ->asThumbs()
            ->enableFilters()
            ->enableUploads()
            ->render(),
        'hiddenLink' => $filePicker->setDirectories($dir['id'])
            ->getLink(lang('field_type_add_image'))
            ->setAttribute('class', 'btn action js-ansel-add-image js-hide')
            ->asThumbs()
            ->enableFilters()
            ->enableUploads()
            ->render()
    );
}
```

I make that available to my template. Now I can select the correct button from the array based on the directory ID.

Then on the Javascript side:

```
$(.js-ansel-add-image).FilePicker({
    callback: function(file, references) {
        // Close the modal
        references.modal.find('.m-close').click();

        // Do stuff
    }
});
```